# ionic client to server sync and client to client sync

Tags: mongodb, ionic-framework, offline, p2p, pouchdb

I'm developing an ionic application where i'm using MongoDb in the backed.
The application needs to work offline so i need to maintain local collections to work in offline mode and then sync the data once the app is online and i also want to replicate the client side collections data to other clients over a Hotspot/Wifi i.e (peer-to-peer).
 
In online mode, the app works using REST Api's, so only for offline and peer-to-peer sync i need solutions.
I have also considered CouchDB and PouchDB but i'm using Mongodb.
I'm open for all kinds of suggestions.
Thanks in advance